# $\sin(z_1)=\sin(z_2)$ implies what?

Tags: complex-analysis

Reading an author's solution to a complex problem, he says "If $\sin(z_1)=\sin(z_2)$, then

$$z_1=z_2\qquad\text{or}\qquad z_1-z_2=2n\pi\qquad\text{or}\qquad z_1+z_2=\pi+2n\pi$$

where $n$ is an integer." Is this true? If so, how can we prove it?

Thanks

Comment: The difference formula $\sin x -\sin y$ is same as in the real case, while the zeroes of sine and cosine are also same $k\pi, \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ respectively. Can you now finish?

Comment: Actually, $z_1=z_2$ is one of the case in $z_1-z_2=2n\pi$, so it is better to not write $z_1=z_2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite $\sin(z_1)=\sin(z_2)$ as

$$\sin(z_1)-\sin(z_2)=2\cos\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\sin\frac{z_1-z_2}{2}=0$$

which has the solutions,

$$\sin\frac{z_1-z_2}{2}=0\implies \frac{z_1-z_2}{2}=n\pi\implies z_1-z_2=2n\pi$$

$$\cos\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}=0 \implies \frac{z_1+z_2}{2} = \frac\pi2+n\pi \implies z_1+z_2=\pi+2n\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall $f(x)= \sin x$ is a periodic function, period $2π$.

$\sin (z_1)=\sin (z_2)$.

1) $z_2=z_1+k2π$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$;

2) Identity: $\sin x =\sin (π-x)$;

(Use $\sin (x-y)=$
$\sin x \cos y -\cos x \sin y);$

$z_2=(π-z_1)+k2π=$

$π(2k+1) -z_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Is a general fact that by definition

$$\sin \alpha =\sin \beta \iff \alpha=\beta+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad \alpha=\pi-\beta+2k\pi$$

[image]

and since $\sin z$ obbeys to the same trigonometric identities as in the real domain, the result holds also on the complex domain.

Comment: This applies to domain $\Bbb R$, not domain $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes but since $\sin z$ obbeys to the same trigonometric identities the result holds also on the complex domain. Am I wrong?